# Getting AWS S3 to work with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm trying to get S3 working with Paperclip. I'm in the process of setting up Aws with rails. So far I've installed the 'aws/s3' gem and setup my access_keys on AWS.

I then added the keys to a s3.yml file:

```
# config/s3.yml
access_key_id: ******************
secret_access_key: ******************
```

**Next I ran:**

```
2.0.0p195 :015 > require 'aws/s3'
 => false 

2.0.0p195 :016 > AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(YAML.load_file('config/s3.yml').symbolize_keys!)
 => #<AWS::S3::Connection:0x007feb03ab2bd8 @options={:server=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :port=>80, :access_key_id=>"******************", :secret_access_key=>"******************"}, @access_key_id="*****************", @secret_access_key="******************", @http=#<Net::HTTP s3.amazonaws.com:80 open=false>> 

2.0.0p195 :017 > AWS::S3::Bucket.create('****')
=> AWS::S3::BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/error.rb:38:in `raise'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:72:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:88:in `put'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:79:in `create'
    from (irb):17
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.0.0p195 :018 >
```

I can't tell if it's working, or what to do next. I am using [this](http://blog.trydionel.com/2009/11/08/using-paperclip-with-amazon-s3/) as a guideline but my results look different. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your bucket has already created, you can try create one with different name